# Embedding Angelscript in a C application and exposing C++ like objects to host (C) application

Tags: c++, c, scripting

I am writing a C application which I want to add scripting functionality to. I have decided to use [AngelScript](http://www.angelcode.com/angelscript/) since it satisfies my requirements and can also be embedded in a C application, using its [C bindings](http://www.angelcode.com/angelscript/resources.html).

However, (this is where things get a little bit trickier). I want to make life eas(ier) for the application scripters, so I want to expose scriptable objects (which are C++ wrappers around my internal C data types etc), so that a user does not have to worry about memory management, dangling pointers etc.)

So, my question is that is it possible to expose C++ objects to AngelScript (for user scripting), whilst embedding the AngelScript engine itself in a C application by means of Angelscripts C binding?.

Comment: you should ask this on http://www.gamedev.net/forum/49-angelcode/
there is a better chance of getting answered there